# Typescript errors as warnings

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting errors in typescript when writing basic javascript ES2015 functions. e.g. I get the following error for not declaring the type everywhere:

> src\app\component.ts(44,18): error TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> src\app\component.ts(44,21): error
>   TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> src\app\component.ts(45,20): error
>   TS7006: Parameter 'p' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> src\app\component.ts(45,23): error
>   TS7006: Parameter 'n' implicitly has an 'any' type.

The '*problem*' function is an ES2015 function like this:

```
this.filters = this.items
  .map(x => x.someProperty)
  .reduce((p,n) => p.concat(n), [])
  .sort((a, b) => {/* sort someway */})
  .reduce((p, n) => {/* do something */}, [])
```

I like the readabilty of this function and I know it works just fine. If I have to add type everywhere it defeats the purpose of having terser syntax.

I understood that Typescript was a superset of ES2015 but everything I write reports as an error (not warning) unless I specify every single type. It's a bit annoying and for some reason the errors crash my compiler.

That being said. I do like writing new code with strong types and I do like getting warnings. Just some in some functions it would be nice to turn off the checks.

Is there away to declare a function that ignores the rules or must I rewrite all my JavaScript in this way?

Comment: have you tried setting `"noImplicitAny": false` in tsconfig compiler options?

Comment: You have just saved me countless hours! Thanks. Please post answer so I can accept.

Comment: Is that code calling reduce on an array of arrays with a label property? I bet it's probably taking an array of objects with a label property and reducing them to the same thing (so the last reduce would be unnecessary), but it's the morning here so I'm probably mistaken :) By the way, in case you don't want to set `noImplicitAny` to false, you can type `this.items` and the types of the parameters in `map`, `reduce`, and `sort` will be inferred for you and the errors will go away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting "noImplicitAny": false in tsconfig compiler options:

```
{ 
     "compilerOptions": { 
         "noImplicitAny": false
     }
}
```